# Error using append dataframe with string data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, fuzzywuzzy

I'm running a loop in matching items using fuzzywuzzy and I'm trying to save the results into a dataframe using `append` but I'm getting the error `AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'append'`

I've been stuck on this for the past couple of days. Ideally I want to add the 5 rows of matches to the bottom of my dataframe -- columns should include the fuzzywuzzy matched item and the corresponding score. Code snippet below...

```
x = 0
matchDF = pd.DataFrame.empty
for index, value in theData.head(5).iteritems():
    lookup = theData.index[x]

    theMatch =  process.extract(lookup, theData.index)
    matchDF = matchDF.append(theMatch)    
    x += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matchDF = pd.DataFrame.empty
```

Returns a property object which don't have append method.
Change it to

```
matchDF = pd.DataFrame()
```

This will work

Comment: That did it. Thank you!!! I’ve been googling this for days and couldn’t figure out the problem.